# Lost access to Desktop Help of ArcMap 10.5?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, windows-10, documentation

Today I found that I can't aceess help on system tools through "**Tool Help**" button. It opens help window which says:

> Can’t reach this page
>
> - Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# is    correct
> - Search for this site on Bing
> - Refresh the page

[image]

I am afraid it is Windows October update in action.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

I tried profile reset and repair installation, no luck.

It is Windows 10 I worry about. The October update was delayed, because it was deleting files on PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution [posted on GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/222786-lost-access-to-help-system-arcmap-105?et=watches.email.outcome) did the trick. Answer by cringo at the bottom of that post is the one.

Comment: Please tell us what you did, that linked page has lots of potential solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I always use the Web rather than Desktop Help but I just tested the latter to see if I could reproduce what you describe in my configuration (which received 11 Windows updates on 10 Oct 2018).

On Windows 7 SP1, using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6, the Desktop Help starts fine from the Windows Start Menu, and I seem to be able to use that to navigate to any of its pages.

[image]

However, when I use the Tool Help button from any geoprocessing tool:

[image]

I get the same as you:

[image]

so I think you should report this to the Technical Support of your Esri International Distributor.

Answer (score 1):

Same error on my side. Even with newest version of ArcGIS 10.6.1 with Windows 7 64Bit SP1.

Comment: Do you mean ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1?  What version of Windows did you test on?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your answer to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Still no reply for my GIS support request 5 days ago.